# Configure job memory in Hadoop 1.2.0

Tags: hadoop

I need to set -Xmx property of a job, running on data node.

On task tracker node I tried to put properties

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.map.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx64m</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.reduce.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx64m</value>
</property>
```

into conf/core-site.xml

but it doesn't have any effect on submitted jobs, I still see java process with -Xmx200m in process list.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.map.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx64m</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.reduce.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx64m</value>
</property>
```

in your conf/mapred-site.xml on each data node.

Comment: should it be done on master node only, or on every data node?

Comment: @jdevelop - on each data node